# Scala: Finding the max element in an array of lists

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an array of lists, for eg.,

```
val arr= Array( List(1, "120", "a"), List(3, "97", "v"), List(7, "110", "d") )
```

I want to find that array element whose 2nd element is the highest of all.
I mean, like

```
arr.maxBy(_(1).toInt),
```

which returns the list (1, "120", "a") as output.

I googled a lot; but was unable to find a solution.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should not be writing code such as `List(1, "120", "a")` in the first place. This is not normal Scala code, because `List[Any]` is not a useful type. Consider storing these values in a tuple instead, or defining a case class to hold them, so the compiler knows which values are `Int`s and which are `String`s.

Comment: @Seth Thanks. Will keep this in mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val array = Array( List(1, "120", "a"), List(3, "97", "v"), List(7, "110", "d") )
> array: Array[List[Any]] = Array(List(1, 120, a), List(3, 97, v), List(7, 110, d))

array.maxBy{ case head :: (second: String) :: _ => second.toInt }
> List[Any] = List(1, 120, a)
```

Each element of the array can be matched to a list with at least 2 elements (head and second). You specify that second is a string since the lists in the array are of type List[Any]. And this way you can take the max by the second element as an int.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: For me, the same code as I mentioned in the question works; ie., arr.maxBy(_(1).toInt). But the problem is, sometimes, I can't see the output fully when I run the code( I am using IntelliJ ). Any idea why it happens so?

Comment: @Skn How are you running it in IntelliJ? If you use a Worksheet you can see each line's output. If you're running it from a normal class you need to use a println to see the output from each line.

Comment: @Chro Of course, I used println. I am running it from the 'main' method of an object. Output is displayed fully, only when the corresponding print statement is followed by no other print statements. Otherwise, only a part of the output is visible.